# Finding reason for server being slow

Tags: networking, cpu, remote-desktop, ftp

The web server was running very slowly, and I couldn’t connect to the server through RDP. I got to know that the CPU usage was 100%. So I restarted my server; the server was still non responsive so I shifted my domains to some other server. I restarted the problematic server again, still the problem not persisted, but after waiting for more that 10 mins the server CPU usage was normalized and the problem solved.

The IIS Worker Process and FTP server was taking 99% CPU alternatively at that time.

I didn’t have any server monitoring software running at the time of the server problem. I found no usable info in event viewer. Is there any way that I can check what was the reason for 100% CPU?

As per the data, there should not be more traffic to this server. I have managed load balancing between two servers manually by hosting different services in different servers. FTP of this server is being used occasionally and that too maximum 15 to 15 concurrent connections for lower sized files.

**Server**:

OS: Windows server 2012 R2

Web server: IIS 8.5

Comment: No you cannot. CPU Monitoring is not logged by default and requires a tool to be logging it. If you haven't, and you stated you didn't, then it can't be traced back.

Comment: You could check the actual access logs and might be able to see any unusual amounts of errors - depending on your configuration for logging. You cant log data retroactively.

Comment: @Seth "actual access logs" i don't know whether you are referring IIS log. I checked the IIS log and there was no much usage found, it was all normal